# Put same DIV twice on same row with space between them

Tags: html, css, width, space

I want to put the same div twice on the same row and cover all of its width and I need to put some space between them both.

The problem is when I use margin it will affect them both since they have same class so the second div will go below the other because the total width will become bigger than the container width.

I tried to use overflow:hidden or `overflow-x:hidden` with margin or change their size but nothing changed.(also I've tried to use borders with overflow hidden)

I am forced to use many div from the same class and I need them to cover all the width of the row.

Edit: the code is big so I will post a small example to explain my question

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="block">content...</div>
    <div class="block">content...</div>
</div>

<style>
.container{width:1000px; margin:0px auto;}
.block{width:480px;height:500px;float:left;}
</style>
```

I want to put first block + 40px space + second block

Comment: Have you tried something yourself? Do you have some code you want to share with us? It would be easier to help you that way.

Comment: As the person who asked the question you can always edit it to add code examples or to clarify some of the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the two .block divs on the same row what I would do is not do it in pixels but with %'s.

For example what I would do is this:

Give your div that you want on the right an id of right and the one that you want on the left an id of left:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="block" id="right">content...</div>
<div class="block" id="left">content...</div>
</div>
```

Then I would style it with

```
<style>
.container{width:1000px; margin:0px auto;}
.block{width:48%;height:500px;display:inline;}
#left{float:left;}
#right{float:right;}
</style>
```

You can play around with the exact width percent to get it to your standards.

Comment: thanks for the reply but I cant give it different ids because I want to make 1 div only and multiply it using PHP while loop thats why I am forced to use same class

Comment: What about having the same class and having the margin left and right be 4 pixels and not having the ids and the floats

Comment: I have thought of this and I think I will use it if there are no other solutions which I need to let them stuck at the left and right to be aligned with the menu and other parts of the page

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance. If this works for you than please choose my answer as the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to make give them different class names or ids if you want to manipulate the two of them different.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="block1">content...</div>
<div class="block1">content...</div>
</div>
```

You can use inline display to make them appear in the same row.

```
.block1, block2 {
display: inline;
}
```

From there you can style them how you want by selecting either of those classes.

Comment: nop, only one class because I am going to use 1 div with while looping

Comment: How about using a pseudo selector in the styling?

Like this:

    <style>
    div div:first-of-type {
    }

    </style>

The first div is to select the container, then they second div is to  select all the divs in that container, but the selector you use will only select the first block. Let me know if this works. I was reading about it on here:

[link]http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-of-type/

Answer (score 0):

Could this be something like you're after?

http://jsfiddle.net/justin_thomas/9S46N/

The CSS:

```
.myRow {
   width:48em;
}
.myclass {
   padding: 1em;
   margin-left:1em;
   margin-right:1em;
   float: left;
   display:inline;
   width: 20em;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="myRow">
  <div class="myClass">Blah... blah...</div> 
  <div class="myClass">Blah... blah...</div> 
</div>
```

In there, i've used floats to get the desired effect. Unfortunately this means you have a hard time if you can't specify the actual width of the row's container in physical units (or one of its parents) and you also need to know whe number of columns there will be in this row to use as the width amount in the class with the divs.

I don't really like this as as solution as you need to make sure that the sum of each (div width + left-margin + right-margin) is never larger than the width of the row container.

Comment: I have thought of this solution to use double margins but divs wont be aligned with other parts of the page

Comment: If you are doing this programmatically, why don't you add a class to div with a generated classname in it (like column1, column2, etc). It sounds like you're trying to do 2 things; use only one class in the div and then also allow that to be positioned where you want it to be.

I think the above solution will only work generically unless you can somehow differentiate each of the divs, it may be hard to align them to the rest of the page (unless you alin the rest of the page to the divs!).